# Rails 4.2.5: Polymorphic has_one association points back to same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have an application where a DB table `things` contains `locatable` objects - like cities, addresses, party places, bus stops and so on.

One locatable object can e.g. be a City and Country. These objects are connected to Thing with a polymorphic has_one association since each City represents exactly one locatable Thing. But Country also `has_many :cities` since all countries are located in a specific country. I am doing all sorts of weird associative requests using this structure and so far (with Rails 3.0) it has worked well. But with Rails 4.2, it fails, see below.

Here is the DB structure:

```rb
  Thing: id, locateable_id, locateable_type, lat, lng, name, country_id, city_id, ...
   City: id, name, country_id
Country: id, name
```

Code:

```rb
class Thing < AR::Base
  belongs_to :locateable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :city
  ...
end

class Country < AR::Base
  has_one :thing, as: :locatable
  has_many :cities
  ...
end

class City < AR::Base
  has_one :thing, as: :locatable
  ...
end
```

In Rails 3.0.20, Ruby 1.9.3, calling this code

```rb
1.9.3-p551 :005 > Thing.find_by_name("Aachen").country.thing
# Thing Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things" WHERE "things"."name" = 'Aachen' LIMIT 1
# Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = 276 ORDER BY name LIMIT 1
# Thing Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things" WHERE ("things".locateable_id = 276 AND "things".locateable_type = 'Country') LIMIT 1
=> <Thing id: 355371, locateable_id: 276, locateable_type: "Country", name: "Deutschland", country_id: 276, ...>
```

would return the city's country. In Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.2.1, the exact same code returns the city's thing again:

```rb
2.2.1 :008 >  Thing.find_by_name("Aachen").country.thing
# Thing Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "things".* FROM "things" WHERE "things"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Aachen"]]
# Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1  ORDER BY name LIMIT 1  [["id", 276]]
=> <Thing id: 105548, locateable_id: 3, locateable_type: "City", name: "Aachen", country_id: 276, city_id: 3, ...>
```

Why? This seems incorrect. Especially since it is inconsistent:

```rb
> Country.find(276).thing
=> #<Thing id: 355371, locateable_id: 276, locateable_type: "Country", coordinate_id: nil, name: "Deutschland", ...>
# but
> c = Thing.find_by_name("Aachen").country
=> <Country id: 276, name: "Deutschland">
> c.thing
=> #<Thing id: 105548, locateable_id: 3, locateable_type: "City", coordinate_id: nil, name: "Aachen", ...>
```

Is this maybe a bug in Rails? Or am I abusing the polymorphic association system?